# How to add method name to all logs in NET Core 7, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I would like to add method/function name to logger so that user defined method/function names are visible in Azure Application Insights. Controller name is logged automatically under ActionName property, however the logging is not occurred in the controller, rather in a user defined method that controller called. So the question is; is there a middleware that i can append all logs which method/function they are called in?
I am developing a NET CORE 7 WebApi and using Azure Application Insights.

Comment: You mean your user-defined methods? So for example if controller calls `_servce.SomeMethod` you want `SomeMethod` to automatically be appended to the logs if it logs something?

Comment: Is this a new project? In that case don't target .NET 7. It [goes out of support](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#lifecycle) in May 2024. It is a short-term release like all odd-numbered .NET versions. The current Long Term Support versions are .NET 6 (supported until November 2024) and .NET 8 (November 2026).

Comment: Put all your logging in a single method that uses [this attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-7.0) and then call it from any method that needs to log its own name.

Comment: @GuruStron yes. exactly what i want to do

Comment: thank you @PanagiotisKanavos . yes, this is a short term project

Comment: What logging interface / facade is in use? The Microsoft Logging stuff? And if so, _how_ are you logging? Are you using [Source-Generated LoggerMessages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logger-message-generator#log-method-constraints)? There, you can specifiy what shall be logged as the source of the log.

Comment: In short - no, you can't do it with middleware.

Comment: `microsoft.extensions.logging` and `microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions`. However i am open to implement any logging nuget as well. I just need a working solution

Comment: @GuruStron is there any automatic way to do that? Append caller method name to all logs?

Comment: `this is a short term project` There's still no reason to use .NET 7. The "automatic" way is better in .NET 8 anyway - [use an Activity in a using block in important methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs#activity). After that you can congfigure an exporter to App Insights. .NET Aspire makes this as easy as [adding 3 lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/deployment/azure/application-insights)

Comment: You don't really need .NET Aspire to push traces/logs to AppInsights. It does take care of the boilerplate code though, allowing you to start really quickly and see some real results before you start digging into activities

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see ASP.NET Core uses logging scopes to implement this functionality ([see for example this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b2dd5b427ba5c21cdc5572d0d9bf94598721c2f7/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/MvcCoreLoggerExtensions.cs#L22)). It can do that because at this point controller and action method is resolved and you can add this info to the scope. Which obviously can't be done for unknown method call down the pipeline (at least in the middleware).

I don't know an easy out of the box way to achieve (I'm pretty sure that there 3rd party libraries that can do that though) but you have several options:

1. Manually manage the log scope in the methods ([see the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#log-scopes)).
2. Create your own extension method over `ILogger` interface which will accept the [caller information attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information). For example:

   ```cs
   public static class LoggingExts
   {
       public static void LogInfoWithCaller(this ILogger logger, string message, [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = "", params object[] p)
       {
           // build new message and log it
       }
   }
   ```

   Though usage will be a bit cumbersome (if you go with `params` parameter for structured logging):

   ```
   logger.LogInfoWithCaller("qweeqw {test}", p: ["Test"]);
   ```

   Something similar done for Serilog [here](https://gist.github.com/litetex/b88fe0531e5acea82df1189643fb1f79)
3. If you are extensively using DI you can use the decorator pattern. For example you can use [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) (or some other automation for such tasks) to generate decorators and register accordingly.
4. Also see [Automatically log scope with `SpanId`, `TraceId`, `ParentId`, `Baggage`, and `Tags`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#automatically-log-scope-with-spanid-traceid-parentid-baggage-and-tags) section of the logs, they can provide some inspiration too.

Comment: Also Activities and OTEL

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue in the past. Here's how I addressed it; feel free to refer to the following and make any necessary modifications, including additional information that you may need to log into the file if required:

I created a new Behaviour that inherits from IPipelineBehavior as below:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using CleanArchitecture.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CleanArchitecture.Application.Common.Behaviours;

public class PerformanceBehaviour<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> where TRequest : notnull
{
    private readonly Stopwatch _timer;
    private readonly ILogger<TRequest> _logger;
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;

    public PerformanceBehaviour(
        ILogger<TRequest> logger,
        ICurrentUserService currentUserService)
    {
        _timer = new Stopwatch();
        _logger = logger;
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        _timer.Start();

        var response = await next();

        _timer.Stop();

        var elapsedMilliseconds = _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        if (elapsedMilliseconds > 500)
        {
            var requestName = typeof(TRequest).Name;
            var userId = _currentUserService.UserId ?? string.Empty;
            var userName = _currentUserService.Name ?? string.Empty;

            _logger.LogWarning("Long Running Request: {Name} ({ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds) {@UserId} {@UserName} {@Request}",
                requestName, elapsedMilliseconds, userId, userName, request);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

After that, you register this new service by adding this line:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(PerformanceBehaviour<,>));
```

The purpose of this function is just for me to log all the information related to a request if its execution time exceeds 500 milliseconds.

Here is what my log above looks like:
[image]

You can simply remove the if condition and all the function names will be written to your logs. By doing so, please note that the log size will be increased massively when your users use the application.